Please avoid surveys, polls, subjective questions, and very broad questions during the beta
After going through several dozen Stack Exchange betas so far, if there's one thing I've learned, is that nothing hurts a young Stack Exchange more than appearing to be a place for dilettantes.
What do I mean by that?
The purpose of this seven-day private beta is to stock up the site with a bunch of on-topic, expert questions and answers about quantitative finance, so that when the site opens to the public, it's already pre-populated with a bunch of the kind of content that will attract other quants.
That means actual, real, objective questions with real answers that a working quant might encounter as a part of their actual, real, job.
It's tempting to start with easy questions, like "what are some good finance books" or "what are the best finance blogs."
Those are not good questions for the private beta, because ultimately, they don't reflect the actual content that we want this site to contain, and are not representative of it.
Now, I don't know much about quantitative finance, but I'm pretty sure the kind of questions that are going to make this site really valuable are going to look a lot more like
"How can I use Mourad Berrahoui's copula approach for pricing CMS spread options with smile?"
and a lot less like
"What blogs should I read".
If you're a quant and you stumble into this site, if you see the pricing question, you might think, "wow, yeah, this is a site for people like ME."
If you see a question about what blogs to read you'll think "Oh boy, not a serious quantitative finance Q&A site."

are we getting enough questions to make it out of beta?

We come out of private beta in 4 days.  In order to make it out of public beta, we need to meet the criteria set forth here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117/quantitative-finance

are we getting enough questions now for our public beta to be likely to succeed?

By my back of the envelope calculation, we need 15 questions a day and we have 46 questions after 3 days, so...yes.
